# Generator vs List Append in Python

Tags: python

For simple list creations, it is recommended to use list comprehension. However, when it comes to more complicated scenarios, spanning the list creation across multiple lines is more advisable.

e.g. for a simple task

```
[x for x in range(10)]
```

e.g. for a more complicated task

```
result = []
for x in complicated:
    if y is complex:
        for z in intricate_stuff:
             result.append(convoluted(z))
```

(I probably would still use a multi-line list comprehension for the above example, but anyways you get the idea.)

Recently, I found myself achieve list creation like that using a generator like:

```
def gen():
    for x in complicated:
        if y is complex:
            for z in intricate_stuff:
                 yield convoluted(z)

result = [x for x in gen()]
```

It's more natural for me to use a generator like this to create a list (well, generate a list), but I feel it might add unnecessary complexity.

Is this recommended? or, which way is more pythonic?

Comment: The point of a generator is that it is *lazy* so you don't need to build the full list at all if you want to process the items one at a time, which saves memory. So what are you doing next with `result`?

Comment: It depends on the use you make of it afterwards. As is, your two bits of code are strictly equivalent. But the generator solution allows you to avoid unnecessarily using memory when you don't need the values

Comment: It is recommended if there is an actual purpose to it being lazy. As a rule of thumb, if it takes less than one second to create the whole thing, and you also only call it once, there is little making it a generator.
@BusyAnt I'd say the readability of the generator is significantly lower - if I saw that code I would ask myself why it was written that way and would probably waste time trying to find a reason.

Comment: Side-note: `[x for x in gen()]` and `[x for x in range(10)]` are not recommended patterns. If the listcomp is non-filtering and non-mutating, you don't need a listcomp, just the `list` constructor, e.g.`list(gen())` or `list(range(10))`, which will be faster and simpler in general. On Python 3.5, you could also use generalized unpacking to go even faster, but Python folks may not be as familiar with it: `[*gen()]`, and `[*range(10)]`.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel this is the answer I want. I know the pros and cons of each, but I was unsure if it's advisable to use generator when both things fit just fine. Since "the readability of the generator is significantly lower," I would stick with plain list construction for cases like this from now on. Thanks! :D

Comment: @ArneRecknagel: I'd argue the opposite. If you have the choice of a function returning a `list`, or generator function (that's basically the same, replacing `append` calls with `yield`s), I'd go with the generator function for flexibility, particularly if the output size is variable length depending on the inputs. With the generator, the caller can iterate directly with fixed memory overhead (handling huge outputs scalably); if they know it will be small, wrapping the function call in `list` makes it equivalent to the `list` based version. If it's `list` based, they don't have that choice.

Comment: Basically, I view the `yield` as being equally obvious, and I consider generators sufficiently desirable that I wouldn't think code using them was unusual enough to warrant investigating the reason for doing so; generator functions are strictly better than functions returning `list`s (see: The bazillion functions/methods changed in Py3 to return generators or views rather than `list`s), so there is nothing to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generators builds the elements on the go, one at a time.
So for statements like:

```
for e in my_generator():
    pass
```

Value of variable `e` is generated each time during iteration, the value of `e` in the previous iteration is not stored. Hence it doesn't store the entire elements of the list. So it is memory efficient.

But if you are planning on using generator inside a list comprehension, there is no point in using generator as all the elements need to be generated and stored.

In that case you can use list comprehension like below:

```
result = [ convoluted(z) for x in complicated if y is complex for z in intricate_stuff ]
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention that generators can also save time. Say you have a complex data curation pipeline. If you you turn every transformation operation into a generator, getting the first fully transformed object is very fasy, making testing and debugging a lot easier.

Comment: the point of using words like "complicated" "complex" is that you shouldn't do a single list comprehension for the creation of such a list. I was arguing the necessity of using a generator when both init-then-append and generator style works fine.